# Determine whether all controls can get focus (i.e. become first responder)

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsresponder

I need to detect whether any `NSControl`, such as an `NSButton`, can get the focus by using the Tab key.

It can, if the user has enabled the option in the System Preferences under Keyboard / Shortcuts / Keyboard / "Change the way Tab moves focus".

More specifically, I like to make a NSButton the first responder but only if the "all controls can get focus" mode is enabled. Maybe I could ask the control if it accepts the firstReponder status?

I tried calling `acceptsFirstResponder` on a button, but that returns YES even if it can't become firstReponder by using the Tab key, so that's not the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`canBecomeKeyView` is the property/method you're looking for.

From [Cocoa Event Handling Guide, Keyboard Interface Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH7-SW9)

> The acceptsFirstResponder method controls whether a responder accepts first responder status when its window asks it to (that is, when makeFirstResponder: is called with the responder as the parameter). The canBecomeKeyView method controls whether the Application Kit allows tabbing to a view. It calls acceptsFirstResponder, but it also checks for other information before determining the value to return, such as whether the view is hidden and whether full keyboard access is on.